# Angular - unable to get the email value in .ts file from ngForm

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get form value in the `.ts` file. Below is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <form autocomplete="off" class="form-signin" method="post" (ngSubmit)="loginForm.form.valid && onSubmit(loginForm)" #loginForm="ngForm">
        <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input 
              type="email" 
              id="input-email" 
              [(ngModel)]="adminemail" 
              #admin_email="ngModel" 
              class="form-control" 
              placeholder="Email address" 
              autocomplete="email" autofocus [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-label-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input 
              type="password" 
              class="form-control" 
              placeholder="Password" 
              autocomplete="new-password" 
              name="password"
              id="input-password"
              [(ngModel)]="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <div>
          <p>
            <a routerLink='/pages'>Forgot Password</a>
          </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In the `.ts` file, I have the following `.html` code:

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
...
...
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  console.log(form.value)
}
```

I see only the value of password in the console log and not the email.

> {password: "123456"}

Comment: Try give your `email` a `name` attribute and see if that works? If your `password` is working, just follow the same pattern with your `email`?

Comment: Since you are using two way data binding you can define the variables `adminemail` and `password` in the .ts. Now in the submit you can do: `onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.adminemail);
    console.log(this.password);
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using two way data binding you can define the variables `adminemail` and `password` in the .ts. Now in the submit you can do:

```
onSubmit() { 
   console.log(this.adminemail); 
   console.log(this.password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormGroup and define those two properties.

**.html file**

```
<form bind-formGroup="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkoutForm.value)">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="address">Address: </label>
            <input id="address" type="text" formControlName="address" />
        </div>

        <button class="button" type="submit">Purchase</button>
    </form>
```

**.ts File**

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedProducts: ProductDto[] = [];
    checkoutForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private cartService: CartService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: '',
            address: ''
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedProducts = this.cartService.getProductsFromCart();
    }

    onSubmit(customerData: UserDto): void {
        // Process Checkout Data here
        console.warn(`Your order has been submitted with Name: ${customerData.name} Address: ${customerData.address}`);

        this.selectedProducts = this.cartService.clearSelectedProducts();
        this.checkoutForm.reset();
    }

}
```